# Python Doubles incorrect value

Tags: python, python-3.x

When trying to add or multiply certain values, double conversion generates incorrect results.

```
>0.1 + 0.2
> > 0.30000000000000004

> 0.1 * 0.1
> > 0.010000000000000002
```

Is there any fix for this other than repetitive round() statements? Thanks!

Comment: Note that Python docs are pretty comprehensive on this as well https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: And finally, there's solutions to some of your problems if you're willing to make the effort to use them (but there's limitations of course) https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html